# use WebView in flutter web without using iframe

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is there a way to use WebView in Web Filter without the need for an iframe?
Most of the methods available by iframe display website information and many sites also prohibit the use of iframe .

I'm looking for a way to use website information directly and **without the need for iframe**

I also tested the lower libraries and it didn't work

**easy_web_view2**

**easy_web_view**

**webviewx**

**web_browser**

**in app webview**

and ...

**I dont have problem to show webview in Flutter webI have trouble displaying sites that have disabled the iFrame feature on their site .**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide testing url and your criteria that how do you want exactly?

Comment: @pratik-butani https://www.chartsaz.com/%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%BE%D9%87%D8%B1 this site or any site that prevent show iframe in your sites

Comment: another example : https://www.sahamyab.com/technical

Comment: Try adding Referer header, and enable cookies

Answer (score 6):

The flutter web directly not support any web view to load url.
You have to use `HtmlElementView` to load URL.

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('openstreetmap', (int viewId) {
      return IFrameElement()
        ..style.width = '100%'
        ..style.height = '100%'
        ..src = 'https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik
'
        ..style.border = 'none';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HtmlElementView(viewType: 'openstreetmap');
  }
```

Comment: Undefined name 'platformViewRegistry'.

Comment: @coditori Checkout this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64748486/1318946

Answer (score -2):

Use `webview_flutter: ^2.0.13` (or latest version)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const WebviewScreen({Key? key, required this.url}) : super(key: key);
  final String url;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'http://www.chartsaz.com/',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

set usesCleartextTraffic property to true in your AndroidManifest file, like below.

```
<application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....>
```

Comment: This library is for Android and iPhone. I also mentioned in the question that I am looking for a suitable solution in Flutter web and a special event