# how to view html files on the android and web platform in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm creating a flutter project that can run on android & web platform.
I'm having problem with viewing html on web platform.

I used a plugin webview_flutter to view html on android platform but this plugin doesn't support web platform.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HelpScreen({super.key});

  @override
  HelpScreenState createState() {
    return HelpScreenState();
  }
}

class HelpScreenState extends State<HelpScreen> {
  WebViewController? _controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext? context) {
    // https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter
    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadFlutterAsset("assets/Help.html");
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'help'.tr,
            style: AppStyle.buildToolbarCommandTextStyle(),
          ),
          backgroundColor: AppStyle.logoGreen,
        ),
        body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller!));
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd see if there was another plugin/method for the web and use logic based on the platform as to which one to use. Viewing html is pretty basic so there must be something out there for the web platform. As to your question - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with more details - like example minimal code for example.

Comment: I added my code, I use that to run for android. thanks for suggesting stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, sorry this is my first time to ask question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using [html_view](https://pub.dev/packages/html_view) instead of the `HtmlElementView` as this `platformViewRegistry` still creates conflict when I run the whole code on android.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:html_view/html_view.dart';

class WebHelpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebHelpScreen({super.key});

  @override
  _WebHelpScreen createState() => _WebHelpScreen();
}

class _WebHelpScreen extends State<WebHelpScreen> {
  final HtmlView htmlView = HtmlView();
  String viewID = "help";
  late final StreamSubscription subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initListener();
  }

  initListener() {
    subscription = htmlView.listen((event) async {
      print(event);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Get screen size
    Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    String styleWidth = '${screenSize.width}px';
    String styleHeight = '${screenSize.height}px';

    // Initialize HtmlView with dynamic size
    htmlView.initView(
      viewID,
      styleWidth: styleWidth,
      styleHeight: styleHeight,
      width: styleWidth,
      height: styleHeight,
      src: 'assets/Help.html',
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'help'.tr,
          style: AppStyle.buildToolbarCommandTextStyle(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: screenSize.width,
        height: screenSize.height,
        child: HtmlElementView(
          viewType: viewID,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But still thankful for your suggestions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`webview_flutter` package is specifically designed for mobile platforms.

If you want to use a web platform, i suggest using [easy_web_view](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) package which automatically uses the `webview_flutter` library to work on mobile platforms and websites.

You may also use `HtmlElementView`. Follow [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872776/use-webview-in-flutter-web-without-using-iframe) to see how to use `HtmlElementView` and when you get the error: `Undefined name 'platformViewRegistry'` follow steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748316/how-to-prevent-error-of-platformviewregistry-flutter-web/64748486#64748486)

Alternatively, you can also do a platform check and change the library conditionally:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```

###### References:

###### 1. [WebView in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150503/webview-in-flutter-web)

###### 2. [How do you detect the host platform from Dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924474/how-do-you-detect-the-host-platform-from-dart-code)

###### 3. [use WebView in flutter web without using iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872776/use-webview-in-flutter-web-without-using-iframe)

###### 4. [How to prevent error of platformViewRegistry [flutter-web]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748316/how-to-prevent-error-of-platformviewregistry-flutter-web/64748486#64748486)

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions. I tried using easy_web_view package, but it's having conflict on a specific package I also have in my project. And the lower version of that package which I don't use cause use the latest depends on easy_web_view package.

Comment: Maybe use another browser widget that works with the web platform.

Comment: @autumn_2309 I see what you mean, apprently the owner of the package hasnt been updating the code with latest flutter versions. May you try using `HtmlElementView` proposed at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69872776/use-webview-in-flutter-web-without-using-iframe)? I tested the solution and it works for me but i'm not sure about your case. Also when you get `Undefined name 'platformViewRegistry'` follow steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748316/how-to-prevent-error-of-platformviewregistry-flutter-web/64748486#64748486)

Comment: @Texv thank you so much for suggesting this **HtmlElementView** it worked for me.
And I understand this now **Undefined name 'platformViewRegistry'**.

Comment: No problem I edited my answer to include it in there, happy coding!